# How do I comment on a post?

Tags: support, comments

I've had several answers deleted because they were more on the order of comments. When I look for a "comment" button on a question or answer there's nothing to be found. I've assumed that I simply don't have enough "credit" yet to comment.

Is that it? Or is there another reason I'm locked out of commenting?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Correct. You need at least **a reputation of 50** if you [want to leave comments on other posts](https://superuser.com/privileges/comment).

This rule does not apply when you are:

- Leaving comments on your own posts
- The person asking - You can leave comments on all posts attached to your question.

Answer (score 7):

On superuser.com, go to the top of the page, where your DanH username is. Hover over it and click privileges. Over to the right you will see what privileges you have and how close you are to achieving others you don't have.