# How do I comment on a question on Super User?

Tags: discussion, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I comment on a thread?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2663/how-do-i-comment-on-a-thread)

I need an author of a question to clarify his question, and I've seen people post comments on questions to do this, yet I can't find a way to. I'm logged in, yet I see no comment option anywhere. Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: Yep, kinda stupid, but you need more reputation to comment.  But you should have that by now, with the up-clicks on your question.

Answer (score 6):

You must have [at least 50 reputation](https://superuser.com/privileges/comment) in order to comment on other users' questions. See also the [Privileges](https://superuser.com/privileges/comment) page.

> [...]
>
> Please note that you can always comment on your own posts, and any part of your questions. However, commenting on other people's posts is a privilege.
>
> #### How do I comment?
>
> Click the `add comment` link under each post. Comments cannot be multi-line, so simply press enter to submit your comment.